# Load next page grid Ext JS 4

Tags: json, extjs, grid, extjs4

I'm trying to load 15 records for each page in the grid: `pageSize : 15,`, the server is sending me exactly 15 page, the problem is that the next page button in the grid is disabled.

**Store :**

```
Ext.define('UserStore', {    
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'UserModel',
autoLoad : true,
pageSize : 15,
remoteSort: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'url/to/servlet',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    },
    writer: {
        type : 'json',
        root: 'data'    
    },
    actionMethods: {
        read   : 'POST',
        create : 'POST',
        update : 'POST',
        destroy: 'POST'
    },
    extraParams : {
        data : 'Blank',
    }

},
sortOnLoad: true,
sorters: { property: 'dateTime', direction : 'DESC' },

});
```

**Grid :**

```
xtype : 'gridpanel',
store : mystore,
height : 350,
columns : [ {
          dataIndex : 'firstName',
          text      : 'First Name',
          flex      : 1
        },{
          dataIndex : 'lastName',
          text      : 'Last Name',
          flex      : 1
        },{
          dataIndex : 'email',
          text      : 'Email',
          flex      : 1  
 }],
 dockedItems : [ {
    xtype : 'pagingtoolbar',
    hight : 28,
    displayInfo : true,
    dock : 'bottom'
} ]
```

**Loading grid :** I have tested 3 methodes :

- `grid.getStore().loadPage(1);`
- `grid.getStore().load({ params:{start : 0, limit : 15}});`
- `grid.getStore().load();`

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: You set your totalProperty attribute to "total". Make sure your server is sending "total:225" in the JSON response. Page size defines how many records per page the grid displays, but it needs the total records count to set it's pagination mechanism. Do you see page 1 of 15 in your toolbar?

Comment: I have edited my post, the image describes the result. You say that the server should send "total:225" you mean that the server is effectively sending 225 records? or just to inform the client of the total records?

Comment: Well, how many records (in total, in your database) is your query fetching? 225 is a random number, its 15 pages x 15 results/page. Say your SELECT * FROM FOO returns 225 results. Then you are responsible of paginating the results from the database and sending only 15 to the client via JSON or whatever other mean. Then, the grid displays 15 results. But, in order for the grid to know it has to provide 15 pages, it needs a "total: 225" attribute/value pair in the response received from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly is due the fact that you are missing totalCount property from data you receive from your Server. 
In this way the grid would calculate the pagination toolbar.